# How to display 3 text box contents into another text box on button click

Tags: javascript, html

how can I make the values of the first 3 text boxes appear on 4th text box on button click? This is just a project build for personal use at work. I'm not able to do it right and is asking for expert help. I also attached the image of the page.[notes generator page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21nIk.jpg)

Here is the code I used:

```
<main>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="innertube">

<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() 
{
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("user_input").value;}
</script>

<form>
<label><b>CUSTOMER ENQUIRY: </b></label>
<br>
<textarea name="enuqiry" cols="70" rows="3" id="user_input"></textarea>
</form>
<br>

<form>
<label><b>TROUBLESHOOTING:  </b></label>
<br>
<textarea name="troubleshooting" cols="70" rows="15" id="user_input2">
</textarea></form>
<br>

<form>
<label><b>RESOLUTION / ADVISE: </b></label>
<br>
<textarea name="troubleshooting" cols="70" rows="3" id="reso"></textarea>
</form>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
<br>

<br>
<label><i>Generated Notes: </i></label>
<p><textarea name="resolution" cols="70" rows="20" span id='display'>
</textarea></span></p>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ..

UPDATE:
output variable is modified to users needs

```js
function showInput(){
  var ui1 = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
  var ui2 = document.getElementById('user_input2').value;
  var ui3 = document.getElementById('reso').value;
  var out = "CUSTOMER ENQUIRY: " + ui1 + '\n';
  out += "TROUBLESHOOTING: " + ui2 + '\n';
  out += "RESOLUTION / ADVISE: " + ui3;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = out ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="innertube">


<form>
<label><b>CUSTOMER ENQUIRY: </b></label>
<br>
<textarea name="enuqiry" cols="70" rows="3" id="user_input"></textarea>
</form>
<br>

<form>
<label><b>TROUBLESHOOTING:  </b></label>
<br>
<textarea name="troubleshooting" cols="70" rows="15" id="user_input2">
</textarea></form>
<br>

<form>
<label><b>RESOLUTION / ADVISE: </b></label>
<br>
<textarea name="troubleshooting" cols="70" rows="3" id="reso"></textarea>
</form>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
<br>

<br>
<label><i>Generated Notes: </i></label>
<p><textarea name="resolution" cols="70" rows="20" span id='display'>
</textarea></span></p>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
<br>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and it now worked. I also have another question, how can I arrange the values on the generated text box? I want it to appear like this:                                                
CUSTOMER ENQUIRY: (fixed value)
customer enquiry (ui1)

TROUBLESHOOTING: (fixed value)
trouble shooting steps (ui2)

RESOLUTION / ADVISE: (fixed value)
resolution (ui3)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! now I can start working on the changes I need for my simple html :)

Comment: great, then please mark this answer as solution (green checkmark) cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function concTables() 
{
var str;
str = document.getElementById("enuqiry").value + " " +
      document.getElementById("troubleshooting").value + ".";
 document.getElementById("resolution").innerHTML = str;


</script>
```

Sorry if I'm misinterpreting the question. This should let you add the string HTML values together.

Do two of your text areas have the same ID? "troubleshooting". You may want to change that. Also, your ID for enquiry is spelled enuqiry, which you may also want to change.